# c sharp finding a specific digit in an int

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the **nth digit** of an integer **(from right to left)**. I'm new to programming but have been using this site a lot for reference - up until now I've resisted passing my problems on but I cannot understand this one in the least, even after hours of effort.

This is the code I have so far but for **FindDigit(int 5673, int 4)** it gives **53** instead of 5, **FindDigit(int 5673, int 3)** gives **51** instead of 6

```
public class DigitFinder
{
    public static int FindDigit(int num, int nth)
    {
        num = Math.Abs(num);
        string answer = Convert.ToString(num);
        int i = answer.Length;

        return ans[i-nth];
    }
}
```

I cannot understand at all why it returns a 2 digit number. Any guidance at all appreciated!

Comment: You need to convert it back to an int. its giving you the ascii value

Comment: You are returning the Character-Code of the digit.

Comment: Don't go through string / char. Use / and % : int dig = (num / (int)Math.Pow(10,nth)) % 10

Comment: Side-note: a method `FindDigit` with parameters `num` and `nth` is not meaningful at all if it actually returns the nth-digit from right to left. If someone would want to use your method, he would expect the wrong from it. Names are important!

Comment: Ooops, actually my above comment is wrong. Correction: `int dig = (num / (int)Math.Pow(10,nth-1)) % 10;`

Comment: Thank you all! Much appreciated! @Tim Schmelter I completely agree, it looks confusing, but the problem was set by someone else with that method name and arguments so I didn't want to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use

```
int result = (num / (int)Math.Pow(10,nth-1)) % 10;
```

Where `num` is the number to get the nth digit from (counted right to left) and `nth` is the "index" of digits you want (again: counted from right to left). Mind that it is 1-based. That is "1" is the rightmost digit. "0" would be out of range.

To explain the math:

`(int)Math.Pow(10,nth-1)` takes your desired index and decreases it by 1, then takes that as the power of 10. So if you want the 3rd digit, that makes 10 to the power of two equals 100.
BTW: the cast to int is necessary because Math.Pow works on double and returns double. But we want to keep on working in integer arithmetic.

Dividing by the result of above equation "shifts" your number to the right, so your desired digit becomes the rightmost digit. Example: 1234, we want 3rd digit from right ("2") => 1234 / (10^(3-1))= 1234 / 100 = 12

You then "cut out" that rightmost digit by applying the "remainder" (modulo) operator with divisor 10. Example: 12 % 10 = [12 / 10 = 1, Remainder =] 2.

Mind that I also would check `nth` to be > 0 and `num` >= 10 ^ (nth-1). (never trust user input)

Comment: very smart! Thank a lot Fildor

Answer (score 4):

53 is the ASCII code of the **character** `5`. Just subtract the character `0`, i.e. numeric 48.

However, it is *usually* a good idea to avoid string manipulation for things like this; *if possible* you should probably prefer division/remainder (modulo) arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your speedy reply! Really appreciate it! I felt string manipulation was an ugly solution but I couldn't come up with anything better. You're right, % would be a lot cleaner i think. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Just because no one else did, and also because i have *Printable Character OCD*

```
public static int GetLeastSignificantDigit(int number, int digit)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < digit - 1; i++)
        number /= 10;
    return number % 10;
}
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vJflOO)